# ResponI am trying to create taking up full height of the page. Left

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create two `<div>` columns,p full height of the page. Left I am trying to create two `<div>` columns, both `<div>`'s taking up full height of the page. LeftI am trying to create two `<div>` columns, both `<div>`'s taking up full height of the page. Left

Answer (score 1):

You should use calc() in CSS.

Here is an example code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fluid">
    Fluid
  </div>
  <div class="fixed">
    Fixed
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.fluid {
  float: left;
  background: #F8E71C;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.fixed {
  float: left;
  background: #B8E986;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0w2qjtz7/

Comment: Why would you have the container float?

Comment: If it's not necessary, ***leave it out***.

Answer (score 0):

Try using giving min-width & use bootrap framework which will give you different grid options

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Is it this way you mean to say 

https://plnkr.co/edit/6J1mBWlfyPxtkfTcH7tL?p=preview